# No route matches the supplied values RedirectToRoute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-routing

I have the following route set up

```
[HttpGet("bar")]
public IActionResult Foo()
```

When I access the website with "/bar", I am directed to `Foo`, as expected.

However, if I try to redirect to "bar", I get an error:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return RedirectToRoute("bar");
}
```

> No route matches the supplied values RedirectToRoute

Why is `RedirectToRoute` not working?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that "bar" is the route template, not the route name. In order to redirect to a specific route, that route must be named. In this case, you can do

```
 [HttpGet("bar", Name = "bar")]
```

This applies to creating routes, as well, such as `Url.RouteUrl`, `new CreatedAtRouteResult` or `CreatedAtRoute`, etc. The route *name* must exist in all cases.

The upside to having to specify the route name explicitly is that you can now change the template without breaking named routes.

```
 [HttpGet("bar?{data?}", Name = "bar")]
```